# Fetch message to another channel if it has a certain number of reactions - discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here's the thingo, I made a feature so that when a suggestion gets a good amount of upvotes (2 for test), it gets the message and sends it to another channel. Here is my code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 723908396599869481:
        if payload.emoji.name == ":upvote:":
            payload.emoji.name = 'upvote'
            channel = client.get_channel(723908396599869481)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            reaction = get(message.reactionsemoji == payload.emoji.name)
            if reaction and reaction.count > 1:
                channel2 = bot.get_channel(759750400621543445)
                await channel2.send('{}'.format(message))
```

However, it does not work, and, an error does not show. Can anyone figure out a fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the emoji will be `upvote` not `:upvote:`.  Additionally, your `get` is structured wrong it should be `get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)` and you should forward the content of the message, not a string representation of the `Message` object `await channel2.send(message.content)`